# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

This is my first post here.  The application is a winform I have set the culture for the application as en-GB but while checking and saving I convert it back to en-US I get this the error String was not recornized as a valid DateTime

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string strCheckDate = CheckConvertCulture(input);
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy");

if (DateTime.ParseExact(strCheckDate,currentCulture.ToString(),null)> DateTime.ParseExact(date,currentCulture.ToString(),null))
{
      return false;
}
else
{
      return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here

This is my converCurrentCulture code

```
string strdate = string.Empty;
CultureInfo currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo usDtfi = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;
if (currentCulture.ToString() != "en-US")
{
    strdate = Convert.ToDateTime(Culturedate).ToString(usDtfi.ShortDatePattern);
}
else
{
    strdate = Culturedate;
}

    return strdate;
```

This is what I did to get it to work, but if a user selects an invalid date like 29/02/2013 will it work not sure,

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", currentCulture);
```

Since the application is default to **en-GB**

```
if (DateTime.Parse(input) > DateTime.Parse(date))
{
  return false;
}
else
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Without a providing a definition for `CheckConvertCulture`, you won't get a good answer.

Comment: What is `strCheckDate` and `CheckConvertCulture`?

Comment: strCheckDate is just the date from a dropdown, need to find out how to edit my code and put CheckConvertCulture :)

Comment: @SonerGönül I added the CheckConverCulture

Comment: @TimSchmelter I tried added this string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy", currentCulture); but still I get that error

Comment: I tried to change the regional settings to **en-US** even then the same error, what am I doing rong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is actually your code:

```
CultureInfo currentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
string strCheckDate = CheckConvertCulture(input);

if (DateTime.ParseExact(strCheckDate,currentCulture.ToString(),null)
```

then the problem is in your ParseExact, which translates to

```
if (DateTime.ParseExact(strCheckDate, "en-US", null))
```

You would be better off specifying the date in a specific format, and parsing that:

```
string format = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
string strCheckDate = input.ToString(format);

// See note below about "why are you doing this?    
if (DateTime.ParseExact(strCheckDate, format))
```

My big question is - why are you doing this?  If you have two dates, why are you converting them both to strings, and then converting them back to dates to compare them?

```
return (input > date);
```

Please see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for the proper use of DateTime.ParseExact.

Comment: I have a combobox that the user select the date so that is in string format then I get the current date and check it with the user date after converting it to the current culture which is en-GB but I save in en-US

Comment: That's ok, but there is no reason to convert the current date to a string and then back to a date.  Don't make things more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: How would I check a string against a date format if I do not convert it?

Comment: You will need to convert the value from the combobox to a date (left side of your if), but you don't have to convert the current date (right side).

Comment: Thanks will try.  But will not the DateTime.Now give you the date and time too.  If so the string after converting will it be able to check if greater?

Comment: If you just want the date, use DateTime.Today